# M 2.3.1: Imprint variables are not showing up in E-Mail templates

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, variables

I have the following problem.

I have populated the bank and imprint data as per *Configuration -> General -> Imprint* for all my store views under Magento 2.3.1

Now I am populating my e-mail template, via "Insert Variable" for example with

- `{{config path="general/imprint/bank_account"}}`
- `{{config path="general/imprint/bank_code_number"}}`
- `{{config path="general/imprint/swift"}}`
- `{{config path="general/imprint/iban"}}`

but whatever I do, the data is not showing in my e-mail preview.

However, when I use the variables

- `{{config path="trans_email/ident_general/name"}}`
- `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}`

all is working fine and showing in my template.

Does anyone have a hint, why the data from imprint (I have filled data under Imprint in Default Config, Main Website and all Store Views) is not showing up at all?

Comment: This appears to use [Firegento MageSetup](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2). There's no tag for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the way to make the variables working: https://gordonlesti.com/magento-2-email-template-config-directives/